# Effective equidistribution inequality for $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: diophantine-approximation, equidistribution

Let $A=\bigg\lbrace k \geq 1 \ \bigg| \ \lbrace k\sqrt{2} \rbrace \lt \frac{1}{2}\bigg\rbrace$ (where $\lbrace x \rbrace$ denotes the fractional part of $x$), $a_n=|A\cap [1,n]|$ and $d_n=\frac{a_n}{n}-\frac{1}{2}$. By the equidistribution theorem, we know that 
$d_n \to 0$ when $n\to\infty$. However, numerical evidence suggests the following conjectures :

(1) $0 \leq d_n \leq \frac{4}{n}$ for any $n\geq 1$.

(2) $d_n=0$ for infinitely many $n$.

(3) $d_n=\frac{4}{n}$ for infinitely many $n$.

The numerical evidence is as follows : for $n\leq 10^6$, (1) always holds, $d_n=0$ holds for 5102 values of $n$ and $d_n=\frac{4}{n}$ holds for 4374 values of $n$. Any ideas on how to prove or disprove any of (1)-(2)-(3) ?

**Update(06/01/2019)** : I expand here on fedja's comment. We have $a_n=f(n\sqrt{2})+\frac{1}{2}$ where $f$ is the $1$-periodic function satisfying $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$ for $x\in [\frac{1}{2},1)$.

It follows that $d_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n f(k\sqrt{2})}{n}$. Now, since the Dirichlet conditions are satisfied for $f$ we have the Fourier expansion (for 
$x\not\in \frac{1}{2}+{\mathbb Z}$)

$$
f(x)=\frac{-2}{\pi}\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2q+1}sin((2q+1)2\pi x) \tag{4}
$$

Taking $x=k\sqrt{2}$ in (4) above, summing on $k$ and using the well-known identity $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k\theta)=\frac{\sin(\frac{(n+1)\theta}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}\sin(\frac{n\theta}{2})$, we obtain

$$
d_n=\frac{-2}{n\pi}\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2q+1)}\frac{\sin(\frac{(n+1)}{2}2\pi(2q+1)\sqrt{2})}{\sin(\pi(2q+1)\sqrt{2})}\sin(n\pi(2q+1)\sqrt{2}) \tag{5}
$$

But I do not see how to continue from here.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q3h147733p845352 ($x=2\sqrt 2$)

Comment: @fedja Correct me if I missed something, but your idea seems to go nowehere. Notice that the inequality I want for $\sqrt{2}$ is trivially false for most values other than $\sqrt{2}$, so the density arguments in your link do not apply.

Comment: Why? The sequence $n2\sqrt 2$ is certainly dense modulo $1$, isn't it?

Comment: @fedja Sure, the sequence is still dense, but there is a problem of uniformity (in $n$) of the bounds. My conjecture only says that a certain infinite sum 
(whose terms depend on $n$) stays between $0$ and $4$. You cannot deduce that all the partial sums stay between $0$ and $4$, or even cruder bounds independent of $n$. The most one can say is that, for a given $n$, there is a constant $M_n$ such that all the partial sums are bounded in absolute value by $M_n$. But there is no reason why $\sup_n{M_n}\lt \infty$.

Comment: Ah, we have some funny misunderstanding then: the post I quoted doesn't *prove* your conjecture; it *refutes* (a part of) it. You cannot have any $O(1/n)$ bound. It doesn't tell you anything about $\ge 0$ though; that is a separate story.

Comment: @fedja We have trouble understanding each other indeed. I understood from the start that your post allegedly refuted not proved my conjecture (or part of it). What I meant in my preceding comment was this : your argument shows that there is no $O(\frac{1}{n})$ bound ON ALL THE PARTIAL SUMS at once. My conjecture is that there is a $O(\frac{1}{n})$ bound ON THE TOTAL SUM ONLY. So what you refute is not a "part" of my conjecture in my view, it's rather a "strengthening" of it (and one which seems not to be helpful here).

Comment: Erm... Your number (1) clearly says "for all $n$", doesn't it?. In that post there is no division by $n$, so your "$d_n$ is $O(1/n)$" becomes "all partial sums are $O(1)$" there", which is exactly what is disproved (unlike $O(1/n)$, $O(1)$ for the "total sum" (sum from $1$ to $n$) implies $O(1)$ for  "all the partial sums at once" (sums from $m$ to $n$) by subtraction.

Comment: @fedja  I see two things wrong with your last comment : 1) the summing is not on $n$ but on $q$ : $d_n$ or $nd_n$ which are functions of $n$ obviously cannot be at the same time sums indexed by $n$. 2) when you say that $O(1)$ for the total sum implies $O(1)$ for all partials sums, this is true only for one fixed total sum, not for a family (indexed by $n$) of total sums  as we have here.

Comment: @fedja To repeat what I already said above : The most one can say is that, for a given $n$, there is a constant $M_n$  such that all the partial sums (associated to the infinite sum for that $n$) are bounded in absolute value by $M_n$, but there is no reason why $sup_n {M_n} \lt \infty $.

Comment: That's getting boring. We are just talking past each other. Let's start it all over and go as slowly as we can to establish some common ground. Do you agree that the condition $d_n=O(1/n)$ is equivalent to the condition $\sum_{k=1}^n f(kx)=O(1)$ for some irrational $x$ (either $\sqrt 2$ or $2\sqrt 2$, does not matter). Next, do you agree that if $|\sum_{k=1}^n f(kx)|\le M$ for all $n$, then $|\sum_{k=1}^n f((N+k)x)|\le 2M$ for all $N,n$? Next, do you agree that, due to the density of $Nx\mod 1$, we then have  $|\sum_{k=1}^n f(t+kx)|\le 2M$ for almost all $t\in[0,1]$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94418/discussion-between-ewan-delanoy-and-fedja).